# Can cookies expire before session expires?

Tags: jsp, servlets, session-cookies

If I defined my custom cookie age as 10 min and I keep my session open for 15 min, will my custom cookie expire?

Comment: Have you tried testing this???

Comment: Yes. Regardless of what you do on the server cookie lifetime is controlled by the client.

Comment: @McDowell.. I left out an important point in my question. Will my custom cookie expire "before" my session ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Cookies are stored at client side and session is managed at server side both are **different** session management techniques.
If you have set cookies expiry time to 10 mins and session expiry time to 15 mins then cookies will expire first and then session.

1. [cookies](http://www.javatpoint.com/cookies-in-session-tracking)
2. [session](http://www.javatpoint.com/http-session-in-session-tracking)
3. [cookie example](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-cookie-example-in-servlet/)
4. [session example](http://www.pretechsol.com/2012/10/servlet-httpsession-example.html#.Uh7hvH-KLXs)
   Its better if you try example on your own. Thanks.